# how to have hierarchy users in sugarCRM Community Edition?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created 6 users say aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff.

cc,dd reports-to aa

ee,ff reports-to bb

When leads are created by cc,dd its visible to both aa and bb users.
How to have only aa-user to see leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CE you'll need to use a teams-like solution such as https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite. Then cc, dd, and aa would all be added to the same teams (same wiht ee, ff, and bb). When cc and dd create a lead it will automatically be assigned to the same team so that aa can see the lead.

For security, a role would be assigned to the team to allow owner only access so that cc and dd only see their own leads (if your needs require this). Then the aa manager-type would be assigned a role with Team level access. In SecuritySuite that would be Group only access which gives the aa user access to his/her own records along with any records assign to aa's team(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply......but i am not clear.....what i need is when cc and dd save the leads it should be visible to only one manager aa whom they reports-to not another bb manager....how to do...help plz.....

Comment: Exactly. So aa would be on the same team as cc and dd. When dd creates a record, that person's team would as be associated with the record. Thus allowing aa to see the record and not bb since bb is not on the same team. Here's a video of how works at a high level. It's not specific to your question, but it is related. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ-BzM3GTgA

Comment: ya..thanks...i tried what u told ....if i assign aa,cc and dd same group with group permission ....then the leads by cc is seen to dd and wiseversa....but what i need is ...leads created by cc should be seen only to aa only(manager) not dd who is his subordinate.....plz help how to do....and set the permissions...plz.....

Comment: You didn't quite follow what I said. Assign OWNER rights to the group so that cc and dd can see only their OWN leads. Assign GROUP rights to aa so that aa can see all of cc's and dd's leads.

Comment: since aa is also in same group if i set owner rights he will not see cc and dd leads ? Plz explain in steps i am not getting....for the two groups( aa,cc,dd) and (ee,ff,bb)... i have tried a lot...plz help.....

Comment: With SecuritySuite, aa would have owner rights as inherited by aa's membership to that time. However, you can also assign a role directly to aa with group rights. The aa user gets the greatest rights by default of all roles directly assigned to the user or assigned to the user's groups in SecuritySuite.

Comment: plz explain in steps ....i am not getting properly...how to assign group and owner rights to whom?which?group or role?fully confused...

Comment: 1) Create a role with Owner rights. 2) Assign Owner role to the group 3) Create a role with Group rights. 4) Assign Group role directly to the manager (aa and bb) 5) Make sure that the group is associated with the appropriate records.

Comment: thanks buddy....really great ur...if i what another hierarchy is it possible.....??? like if i what some hh person who is manager of  aa and bb(retaining above hierarchy like cc,dd,ee,ff subordinates)....how to set permissions...should i create new group...?role??so that aa can't see bb leads and viseversa....

Comment: Yes, just keeping building groups and follow the same pattern. There's a bit of a learning curve sometimes, but you get the idea now.

Comment: ya....i am getting ideas now how to build....i will try to build another hierarchy .......thanks for support....great job....